# Errno::ECONNREFUSED: No connection could be made because the target machine acti vely refused it. - connect(2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am doing the following to create a user in my database:

```
user1 = User.new

user.update_attributes(fname: "john", lname: "doe", email: "random@random.com",     location_id: "99999", password: "foobarfoobar")
```

Once I do this the console starts to go through the process of inserting the user into the database and sending me the confirmation email. But then it runs into this:

```
<p><a href="http://localhost:3000/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=sMc6rFpT
bMCgTxa2Hq3o">Confirm my account</a></p>

   (3.0ms)  rollback transaction
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: No connection could be made because the target machine acti
vely refused it. - connect(2)
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:540:in `init
ialize'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:540:in `open
```

It gives me a lot of code but something here seems to be the problem and I have no idea how to solve it. I looked around but couldn't find the solution, any suggestions?

Comment: Err.. your database connection does not work?

Comment: Is that it? How do I fix it?

Comment: Use a connection string that is valid?

Comment: I ended up using mail catcher gem and the problem was fixed. I had no idea about this before but figured it out thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used the mail catcher Gem and it solved the problem.